# Is open source limited to software?

Tags: discussion, scope

In *open source*, are we talking only about software, or also about other things?  There is free documentation (GFDL, Creative Commons), open data (already has its own Stack Exchange site), open recipes...

Does this site want to be broad in scope, or narrow in scope?

Comment: I'm very much in favour of staying broad and including open source hardware, education and documentation. Do we want to draw a line somewhere though? What about [open source beverages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source#Beverages) and [open source fashion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source#Fashion)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### No way!

[As was previously discussed on the Area51 proposal](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19436/109139), we should be looking to accept questions about the application of open source principles and models, whether or not they involve software.

On Engineering Stack Exchange, we've fielded a question about [open source aircraft components](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/183/368). There are "open source" designs for creating things with 3D printers and even [an emerging open source automotive industry](http://www.business2community.com/automotive/will-open-source-drive-future-automotive-industry-01252556).

This is an area that has already grown beyond the software industry and continues to grow. We should welcome that, and focus on the common problems and solutions that open source presents, regardless of the field of application.

Answer (score 13):

I think broader is better. If we are narrow in scope we have problems getting quality questions later.

However, if there is already a site dedicated to specific aspects of Open Source and a question is more on topic there, we should migrate such questions. [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) is one such site. It already has the user base and traffic to handle such questions.

I think we should encompass *all* open source and only carve out exceptions for very specific things that are more on topic elsewhere.