# Off-topic reason restricts to software

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, scope, close-reasons

The off-topic close reason suggests only software is on topic, which the community appears to disagree with, both on Area 51 and here on [Meta](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-open-source-limited-to-software).

> off-topic: This question does not appear to be about open source *software*, within the scope defined in the [help].

It is therefore important that this be corrected as soon as possible, and certainly before starting public beta, where the reason will be presented to new people who have not been informed of our scope.

Please propose alternative wordings in answers to this question, so the community can use voting up and down to indicate preference.

Comment: I see the one answer, I'm like great! Perfect! I scroll down, *Oh god, how many reasons did this guy write!?!?*

Comment: I just thought I'd give people choices so we can see how the votes go - they seem pretty conclusive.

Comment: No I know, it just surprised me to see so many options...

Comment: Case in point: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/open-source-solution-for-unmasking-harassing-skype-callers is certainly “about open source software”, yet it's off-topic.

Answer (score 11):

Proposed wording:

> off-topic: This question does not appear to **relate to** open source, within the scope defined in the [help].

(Changed wording in **bold** - the final close reason will not require bold.)

Comment: I've used this as the new reason, given it was the highest voted.

Answer (score 3):

Proposed wording:

> off-topic: This question does not appear to be about open source **concepts**, within the scope defined in the [help].

(Changed wording in **bold** - the final close reason will not require bold.)

Answer (score -4):

Proposed wording:

> off-topic: This question does not appear to be about open source **principles**, within the scope defined in the [help].

(Changed wording in **bold** - the final close reason will not require bold.)

Comment: I don't like this one because it seems to imply that this site is only about ethics and excludes concrete problems.

Answer (score -5):

Proposed wording:

> off-topic: This question does not appear to be about open source **projects**, within the scope defined in the [help].

(Changed wording in **bold** - the final close reason will not require bold.)

Comment: I don't like this one because it seems to imply that questions about open source projects are on-topic, e.g. “how do I view Flash videos in Firefox”.

Comment: I don't like it because it seems to narrow the scope - questions without relations to a specific project will be regarded as off-topic